# How do I access UIButtons in extensions?

Tags: ios, swift, button, compiler-errors

I am new to swift, please bear with me.

I am trying to enable a button in an extension outside the main ViewController class. Basically, I only want the button to work if the user's Bluetooth antenna is on and working. It looks like this:

```
extension UIViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

        //function called after manager is initialized, state of bluetooth on manager
        public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: 
CBCentralManager) {
            switch central.state {
                  case .unknown:
                    print("central.state is .unknown")
                  case .resetting:
                    print("central.state is .resetting")
                  case .unsupported:
                    print("central.state is .unsupported")
                  case .unauthorized:
                    print("central.state is .unauthorized")
                  case .poweredOff:
                    print("central.state is .poweredOff")
                  case .poweredOn:
                    print("central.state is .poweredOn")
                    connectButton.isEnabled = true
               
                  @unknown default:
                    print("central.state is .unknown")
            }
        
        }
}
```

As you can see, under the .poweredOn case, I try to enable my button. However, I keep getting 'Use of unresolved identifier' errors. Here is how I declare my button:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var voltageOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet public var connectButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        connectButton.isEnabled = false
        //initializing manager
        myVars.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func connectButton(_ sender: Any) {
        connect()
    }
}
```

I have been googling for hours, I tried making the class open/public, and when I declare my button outside of the class, I get a different error by 'connectButton.isEnabled = false' in the override function. What can I do to access my button outside the main ViewController class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are extending the base class UIViewController, instead of extending your subclass ViewController. The base class knows nothing about properties you declare in your subclass.

Change

```
extension UIViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
```

to

```
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the extension for the vc name not for generic `UIViewController` that acually doens't know anything about `connectButton`

```
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
```